# Is it possible to play Grand Theft Auto V Online cross platform?

Tags: ps4, grand-theft-auto-online, xbox-one

If I had a XBox One, and a friend of mine had a Playstation 4, would we be able to play GTA Online together?

Answer (score 1):

No! You can't play.If you want to play with your friend then you both must have same consoles and should purchase Xbox Live for Xbox and Playstation Plus for playstation.